# Condition always true for null check in iterator

Tags: java, intellij-idea

I have the following code.

```
for (String line: lines) {
    if (line != null) {
        // Do stuff with lines
    }
}
```

IntelliJ has marked the expression `line != null` as always true.

This doesn't seem correct to me, since null elements are allowed in lists. Is this a bug? Is there some inspection setting I can disable? (I still want the inspection in general, so disabling the inspection entirely is not valid.)

**EDIT:** It seems to be related to an annotation `@NonnullByDefault`. Removing the annotation from the package removes the warning. This still surprises me, since the iterator for the collection should still be in a different package, and therefore the annotation shouldn't apply.

Comment: What's the type of `lines`?

Comment: Relevant to @immibis's comment, if your list type is one of the Guava immutable types, or is one of the `java.util.concurrent` container types, those are known to forbid storing nulls.

Comment: It doesn't seem to matter what the type of `lines` is. I tried `ImmutableList`, `Lists.newArrayList`, `new ArrayList<>()`, `new LinkedList<>()`. All of them display the same warning.

Comment: Have you tried creating a `lines` with a null entry in it? For example, `List<String> lines = new ArrayList<>(); lines.add(null);`

Comment: Yes, I even tried directly implementing an iterable/iterator that returned null as every other entry.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that the lines variable is initialized. I have a feeling that lines is an empty array, in your case. If that is not the case, please provide some more context.

Comment: If it's an empty array and Intellij is making that analysis, the whole block is dead code.

Comment: If lines is null, then `lines` gets highlighted, not `line != null`.